# The logits in the loss in tensorflow can be a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I use tensorflow to implement handwritten digit recognition. I hope that the logits in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits are first represented by a placeholder, and then passed to the placeholder by the calculated value when calculating, but tensorflow will report error ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check Your graph for ops that do not support gradients. I know that it is ok to change the logits directly to outputs, but if I have to use logits, the result is a placeholder first. How should I solve it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/as/downloads/resnet-152_mnist-master/mnist_dataset", one_hot=True)

from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

hidden1 = fully_connected(x,100,activation_fn=tf.nn.elu,
                         weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1,200,activation_fn=tf.nn.elu,
                         weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
hidden3 = fully_connected(hidden2,200,activation_fn=tf.nn.elu,
                         weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())


outputs = fully_connected(hidden3,10,activation_fn=None,
                         weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())




a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])


loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=a)
reduce_mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

equal_result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputs,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
cast_result = tf.cast(equal_result,dtype=tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(cast_result)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(reduce_mean_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(30000):
        xs,ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        result = outputs.eval(feed_dict={x:xs})
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={a:result,y:ys})
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be brief, the logits in your loss can't be a placeholder, but need to be a tensorflow [Operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation). Otherwise, your optimizer can't calculate the gradient w.r.t any variables (see error message).

Operations are "a graph node that performs computation on tensors", whereas a [placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) is a tensor that needs to be fed, when evaluating the graph.
I don't really understand, why you don't directly assign the outputs operation to logits, like so:

```
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=outputs)
```

I could try to further help you, if you provide a special use case?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you are familiar with reinforcement learning, you will understand that the problem I face is that my program has two neural networks. These two neural networks have the same neural network. Sometimes what I need is that the results of the first neural network are passed to logits, sometimes the result of the second neural network is passed to logits, so I can only pass the placeholder to logits first. If I don't use logits=placeholder, what should I do?

Comment: I'll try to summarize, what I understood. Please correct me, if I'm wrong. You have two neural nets with the same architecture and you want to use only one of their outputs to compute the loss (based on some condition). If so, you could use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), and a placeholder for the condition, to select the output to use.